# Adding an additional argument to the column for a Spark user defined function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

is there a way to add an argument to a spark UDF in addtion to the column. I know you can use currying in Scala, but it doesn't work as I like it to.

Lets take this function as an example:

```
def containsWord(word: String, words: Seq[String]): Boolean = {
  for (w <- words) if (word.contains(w)) return true
  false
}
```

The word string is the parameter I want to get out of the column. Without the second argument I could create the UDF with the `udf` function and give it the column as parameter. How can I add the String sequence in the UDF call?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need currying here (although the idea is similar). You can just define a function that takes your sequence as a parameter and returns a udf:

```
def containsWord(words : Seq[String]) = udf((word : String) => words.contains(word))
```

And then use it like this:

```
sc.parallelize(Seq("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
    .toDF("A")
    .withColumn("B", containsWord(Seq("a", "b", "d"))($"A"))
    .show
```

And it gives you this:

```
+---+-----+
|  A|    B|
+---+-----+
|  a| true|
|  b| true|
|  c|false|
|  d| true|
|  e|false|
+---+-----+
```